# Change value of Enum

Tags: c#, reference, enums

I am reading about `Enums` and came across an example where the writer showed how we can `typecast` an `enum` to `int` and an `int` to an `enum`. However I didnt get how can we change the value of an enumeration by creating a reference of type `TrickScore`.

```
public enum TrickScore {
     Sit = 7, 
     Beg = 25,
     RollOver = 50,
     Fetch = 10,
     ComeHere = 5,
     Speak = 30,
}
```

This code block changes the value of `Fetch` enumeration. I am unable to understand how score gets set to `TrickScore.Fetch`. When I call `score.ToString()`, it returns `Fetch`.

```
int value = (int)TrickScore.Fetch * 3;
MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
TrickScore score = (TrickScore)value;
MessageBox.Show(score.ToString());
```

Comment: No it [doesn't](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZehC73). It returns `Speak` because `10 * 3 = 30` and `30` is the value for `Speak`. Also please don't mix up enumerator with an enumeration (enum).

Comment: And, to clarify, the values in `TrickScore` are constant. They can't be changed and you can't assign new values to them. What you think you are doing isn't actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your understanding of `enums` is not quite right. This line of code:

```
int value = (int)TrickScore.Fetch * 3;
```

doesn't change value of `TrickScore.Fetch`. It takes the value of `TrickScore.Fetch` (10) multiplies it by 3 and assigns it to a variable `value`. In this case you are using `TrickScore.Fetch` almost as if it were a variable that keeps a number. When you have something like `y = x * 5` you don't change a value of `x`. Only assigning the result to `y`.

Next line in your code that does something is this one:

```
TrickScore score = (TrickScore)value;
```

So you have your variable `value` (30) from previous operation. You cast the value to `TrickScore` enum type. The item with this number is `Speak` and it is assigned to the `score` variable.

One thing worth noting is that only because `enum` inherits from `int` doesn't mean it's a good practice to perform arithmetic operations on `enums`. I'd avoid casting them on `int`s and performing mathematical operations. After all does it really make sense to add up `TrickScore.Beg` and `TrickScore.ComeHere` and expect it to result in `TrickScore.Speak`?

Comment: "Don't do math with enums" is a little broad. It doesn't make sense when the numeric values have no meaning (like in this case), but it can make sense when they do. For example, with an enum representing the days of the week, it can make sense to say `tomorrow = today + 1` (although you need to handle the edge conditions, so something like: `tomorrow = (today + 1) % (daysOfTheWeek.Sunday + 1)`). It also makes sense when dealing with flags to use the logical operators.

Comment: @MattBurland I definitely agree that when operating on flags bitwise operations are very handy. Also, I didn't say "don't do math" but rather "it's not recommended". Still, as you pointed out, there are cases when it may be useful. But it's not usual. And even then you have to be very careful. As to your example: 1) how does it make sense that Tuesday + Wednesday == Friday; 2) what should I get when casting 8 on `daysOfWeek`? Monday? How is 8 and Monday related. Also, when casting 15 I'll get Monday as well. So suddenly a bunch of numbers is equal to Monday which is confusing.

Comment: I still think even "not recommended" is too broad a statement. "don't do it when the actual numbers are meaningless" would be a fine statement. As for your other points, casting `15` absolutely does not give you `Monday`, it gives you `15`. Enums don't automatically wrap their values (which is why I had the mod (`%`) part). Adding `Tuesday + Wednesday` is clearly nonsense and shouldn't be done. There might be an example where adding two enums together (versus adding an int to and enum) might make sense, but I can't think of one right now.

Comment: Days of week and numbers are two very different entities. Coincidentally it makes sense to add 1 to current day. But there is plenty of edge cases (like dividing a day by a number; why Tuesday/2 gives you Monday and not Tuesday noon).If I need a day of week value to perform SOME operations I'd rather implement it as a class (maybe class wrapper around the enum) so I can prevent user of the class/enum from accidentally performing some nonsensical operations. The enum on its own doesn't provide such constraints. enum being stored as int is only a implementation detail, not a feature of the type.